# Adding actions or any other options?

Tags: qgis, pdf, actions

I am pretty new with all GIS things and I have to prepare homework in QGIS.

I have a shapefile which contains many buildings with their own grades. I want to make an automatic tool, solution, etc. to reach the related pdf reports of each building by clicking.
I read something about actions but I am so confused.

Is there clear way to do this or any source to find about this topic?

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html

Answer (score 2):

simply if there is direct know relation then make a new column in the shape file and fill it like this

\fileserver\filefolder\file 1.pdf

then

1) in the properties go to action

2) create a new action of type Generic , name it open and add

```
cmd /c [% "url" %]
```

as action. done.

Now to see pdf just select the Action icon, move the mouse over the point and click on feature.